# Переход из surfaceview на activity

Tags: android, java

Я уже задавал подобный вопрос, но сейчас ситуация немного другая: нужно при столкновении перекинуть на активность с сообщением, что проиграли. Делал:

```
Context context = getContext(); 
Intent intent = new Intent(context, FiledActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Но оно никакой реакции. Может есть какой-то другой способ, потому что я так понимаю, что этот вариант для клика?

**UPD:** 
Полностью вся функция:

```
private void testCollision() {
    /*Движение с лево на право по Х*/
    Iterator<SpriteListX> i = rx.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        SpriteListX sp = i.next();

        if ((Math.abs(sp.x - p.x) <= (sp.width + p.width) / 2f)
                && (Math.abs(sp.y - p.y) <= (sp.height + p.height) / 2f)) {
                  i.remove();

                  this.running = false;

                  Context context = getContext(); 
                  Intent intent = new Intent(context, FiledActivity.class); //а не new Intent(this, MyActivity.class)
                  context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну же люди, разве никто не знает?

Comment: покажи лучше код-условие перехода на твое сообщение, а то это просто вызов, которые как бы должен сработать

Comment: сложновато что-то сказать по этому методу, я бы советовал, зайти и промониторить все в дебагере, посмотреть или срабатывает условие 

if ((Math.abs(sp.x - p.x) <= (sp.width + p.width) / 2f)
                && (Math.abs(sp.y - p.y) <= (sp.height + p.height) / 2f)) {

Comment: столкновения срабатывают все на отлично, а ври переход не пашет.

Comment: вылетает ошибка?)))

Comment: ничего не вылетает, в том то и дело)) просто играет дальше и все

Comment: ставь брейкПоинт на this.running = false; и смотри пошагово до context.startActivity(intent); у меня варианты закончились)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<activity
    android:name=".FiledActivity"/>
```

Comment: а вот теперь вылетает ошибка!

Comment: значит тут я был прав и ты не зарегистрировал активити в манифесте?

Comment: не зарегистрировал, но терь ошибка хоть появилась)) Пасибо

Comment: теперь даже мне интересно стало, в чем там может быть еще ошибка =) обычно если не зарегистрировано - ошибка вылетает, если зарегистрировано, в этом случае, - должно все работать... короче, если разберешься -  отпиши в чем она была, если не разберешься - тоже пиши )

Comment: Такое просто решение не давало мне продолжить писать целую неделю, пилять да это уже маразм какой-то... Спасибо дружище!